# how to set default v-calendar visible months

Tags: vcalendar

I'm working with V-calendar to select date ranges

The default v-calendar view shows me the current month and the next month
(today is febury), like:

[image]

However I would like to set default view from current and past month, cause the default range is the last 30 days
, like:

[image]

How can I set this in my v-calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by setting the `from-page` and  `to-page` props. like

```
<DatePicker :from-page="fromPage" :to-page="toPage" mode="range"/>
```

And use `momentjs` to get these parameters

```
  get currentMonth() {
    const month = moment().month()+1; // 0 to 11
    const year = moment().year();
    return { month, year };
  }

  get previousMonth() {
    const month = moment().subtract(1, "month").month()+1; // 0 to 11
    const year = moment().subtract(1, "month").year();
    return { month, year };
  }
```